# S3 Storage in surrealdb

Tags: surrealdb

Surrealdb uses `memory, file:<path>, tikv:<addr>, file://<path>, tikv://<addr>` to store data.

Is there any way to store data in S3 or decentralized storage like storj (which is s3 compatible)

Mountpoint https://github.com/awslabs/mountpoint-s3 may the solution, but its in alpha and not sure how to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

At present, SurrealDB does not have the capability to store files in S3. It does, however, support memory and local file storage. As a workaround, you could create a logic to persist data structures in a file at S3 using the official library when using SurrealDB memory. Alternatively, you could upload the SurrealDB folder to S3 when using the database file persist type, but this is not ideal.